# kotlin generic type which implement set of operators

Tags: kotlin, generics, operator-overloading

i want to write a function which operates on any generic type T which has implemented set of operators,

for instance this function should work for any `I` and `O` which implements:
`I.plus(I): I`
`I.times(Int): I`
`O.plus(O): O`
`O.div(Int): O`

```kotlin
typealias GeneralFunction<I,O> = (I) -> O

// takes in a function and produce an averaged version of it
fun <I,O> deNoise(func: GeneralFunction<I,O>, h: I): GeneralFunction<I,O> = { i: I ->
   (func(i + h*2) + func(i) + func(i-h*2))/3
}
```

i can't figure out how to define boundary for my generics to make this snippet compiled,
i tried to write a generic interface `FieldOps<T>` which declares set of required operators
but i can't use this approach for already existing types like `Double`

the goal is here to:

- not loosing generality
- avoiding boilerplate
- avoiding any overheads

so any suggestions respecting these criteria is welcomed,

- thanks in advance

Comment: @Sweeper for I i just noticed i have to write ` i+ h * 2` if this is what you are pointing to, for O in other hand i can't see why, can you elaborate ?

Comment: yes and `O.div(Int): O` will suffice for that wouldn't it? @Sweeper

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read the signatures correctly.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `2*h` requiring `Int.times(I): I` though i would edit this

Comment: You actually also need a `minus` or `unaryMinus` for the subtraction to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use an interface like `FieldOps` that has all the operators. You just need to create a wrapper around the primitives:

```
interface FieldOps<I, O> {
    fun I.plusi(x: I): I
    fun O.pluso(x: O): O
    operator fun I.times(x: Int): I
    operator fun O.div(x: Int): O
    operator fun I.minus(x: I): I
}

// resolve JVM signature conflict
context(FieldOps<I, *>)
@JvmName("fieldOpsPlusi")
operator fun <I> I.plus(x: I) = plusi(x)

context(FieldOps<*, O>)
@JvmName("fieldOpsPluso")
operator fun <O> O.plus(x: O) = pluso(x)
```

```
class FieldOpsWrapper<I, O>(
    private val plusi: (I, I) -> I,
    private val pluso: (O, O) -> O,
    private val times: (I, Int) -> I,
    private val div: (O, Int) -> O,
    private val minus: (I, I) -> I,
): FieldOps<I, O> {
    override fun I.plusi(x: I) = plusi(this, x)
    override fun O.pluso(x: O) = pluso(this, x)
    override operator fun I.times(x: Int) = times(this, x)
    override operator fun O.div(x: Int) = div(this, x)
    override operator fun I.minus(x: I) = minus(this, x)
}
```

If you prefer it with a single type parameter, like `FieldOps<I>` and `FieldOps<O>`, you can do that too, but this might introduce some ambiguity later down the line.

Then you can create instances of `FieldOpsWrapper` for each primitive you want:

```
val intField = FieldOpsWrapper(Int::plus, Int::plus, Int::times, Int::div, Int::minus)
val doubleIntField = FieldOpsWrapper(Int::plus, Double::plus, Int::times, Double::div, Int::minus)
```

Rather than using `FieldOps` as a generic bound, use it as context receiver instead:

```
context(FieldOps<I, O>)
fun <I,O> deNoise(func: GeneralFunction<I,O>, h: I): GeneralFunction<I,O> = { i: I ->
    (func(i + h * 2) + func(i) + func(i - h * 2)) / 3
}
```

Or if you prefer having separate `FieldOps<I>` and `FieldOps<O>`,

```
context(FieldOps<I>. FieldOps<O>)
fun <I,O> deNoise(func: GeneralFunction<I,O>, h: I): GeneralFunction<I,O> = { i: I ->
    (func(i + h * 2) + func(i) + func(i - h * 2)) / 3
}
```

Then to call this, introduce one of the `FieldOps` instances with `with`:

```
fun caller() {
    with(intField) {
        deNoise(...)
    }
}
```

The thing with context receivers is, you don't actually need to introduce this context receiver every time, if you just mark `caller` as having the same context receiver:

```
context(FieldOps<Int, Int>)
fun caller() {
    deNoise(...)
}
```

You can propagate the context receiver all the way up the call chain (kind of like `suspend`), until the very end, where you'd use `with` to introduce the context receiver.

So this is kind of like marking what parts of your code deals with what types of numbers. It works best when different parts of your code works with different types, e.g. one group of functions deals with `FieldOps<Int, Double>`, another separate group of functions deals with `FieldOps<Float, Short>`, as opposed to one function dealing with `FieldOps<Int, Double>` and `FieldOps<Float, Short>` at the same time.

Comment: this is great indeed, just one concern
does this add any runtime overhead?  it's obvious i need this for a computational program, if i wrap primitives like this would jvm still optimize this?

Comment: Of course there is. You are passing around the `FieldOpsWrapper`s. And at least on JVM (don't know how this works on other platforms), an extra object needs to be created for each of the function-type parameters you passed to `FieldOpsWrapper`. Whether that matters to you, you'd need to measure it yourself. @HumanArdaki